# I want to run two or more simulink model in parallel and synchronisation.

Tags: matlab, simulink

Hi I want to run two or more simulink model in parallel and synchronisation. is there any way to do it? One way I think is by creating a subsystem and put all models inside it. It should run parallely. This one is not prefered for me. I want to open two matlab instances and run two different model in synchronisation. is this possible? I want to do it programmatically. Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a matlab script and implement the synchronization logic in it.

== Update ==

You can execute the simulink model by simply calling it from a Matlab Script. 
You have to define a task containing the next steps: First you can calculate inputs in Matlab. Then execute the first model with the first inputs. Then save the results to a certain variable. Finally use that variable on the second model and launch second model simulation.

Repeat the task for all the necessary steps.

Comment: what should be the synchronization logic ? I am not able come up with appropriate matlab command for synchronization

Comment: Can you describe the nature of your system? Probably data generated on the first model will be used on the second. Am I right?

Comment: yes, Output of one modle should be fed to another model but it should happen in synchronisation. means the moment, simulink calculates out1(output of model 1), this out1 should be fed to in2( input of model_2); so in next cycle out2 should be populated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Instrument Control Toolbox, you can send/receive data between the two models via [TCP/IP](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/tcpipsend.html) or [UDP/IP](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/udpsend.html) blocks. No need to have two MATLAB sessions, this can be done from one MATLAB session, see this [loopback example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/instrument/building-simulink-models-to-send-and-receive-data.html).

However, I would query the need to have two separate models. Why not put both models in the same model as subsystems, or even as Model blocks if you want to keep the atomic nature of each sub-model?

Comment: That is not available in my matlab license, any way thanks for ur answer.

Comment: OK. I would still question the need to have two separate models. Why not have both models in the same model as subsystems or referenced model blocks? Then the whole problem of synchronisation goes away.

Comment: yes I agree with you. But I need to simulate two process with different environment like different configuration parameter.

Comment: and also the model will run parallelly or serially?

Comment: If you have two model blocks, each model can have its own set of configuration parameters, see http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/model.html. If you have only one model, the question of parallel or serial running is irrelevant.

Comment: yes obviously for two models, when you put two model in one subsystem then they will run parallaly or serially ? that is my concern.

Comment: anyway i'll try 2nd suggestion, different configuration parameter for different model

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run parallel simulink simulations is probably the `parsim` command. Their is a complete article on the Mathworks website explaining how to do it:

[Run Parallel Simulations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/parsim.html)