# Share data between two simulink models

Tags: simulink

Lets say I have following model

[image]

And I want the block in red to come from another model.I want them the two  models to run independently and having them talk to each other. 
I have read this https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/share-data-with-other-matlab-system-blocks.html but I didn't help me

Comment: The easiest approach is the use UDP communication.  The second answer to [I want to run two or more simulink model in parallel and synchronisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288319/i-want-to-run-two-or-more-simulink-model-in-parallel-and-synchronisation) answers your question although the asker of that question hasn't accepted the answer.

Comment: I have tried this but the problem the UDP doesn't accept continuous input

Comment: When transfering data from one model to another it's always going to have to be discretized in some way.

Answer (score 2):

You're not really sharing data, you are asking about using one model inside another model.  For this you want to use the [Model Reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/model-reference.html) block.

Comment: So if I will two model simulationsly one will transfer the signal to another and vice versa

Comment: Your question doesn't ask about running 2 models independently and having them talk to each other.   What you have described is a situation of having one model as a component of another model.  That is what the Model Reference block is for.

Comment: maybe I was not clear enough but that what I need.I edited the question to make it more clear